# Wordpress uncaught Typeerror with jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I run may page I get

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function -----(index):475

(anonymous function)--------- (index):475

n.event.dispatch    -----jquery.js?ver=1.11.0:3

r.handle  ------  jquery.js?ver=1.11.0:3

CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(window).load(function(){
  jQuery('#bokeh, #tooltips_sample, #hotspots_sample, #bullet_1, #bullet_2, #bullet_3, #bullet_4').ShowCase();
 });
</script>
```

Someone how can see what the problem are??

Comment: first add jquery file then check ShowCase like plugin are also added before this statement

Comment: add the `showcase` related library or function after jQuery library.

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script src="wp-content/themes/onetone/showcase/js/jquery-showcase-2.2.min.js"></script>
This is the order they are in